# bluetooth socket connection with bluetooth headphones / Python

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth, oserror, pybluez

This is the occuring error message. I cant establish a bluetooth socket connection with my airpods.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 554, in _clicked
    self._command()
  File "C:\Users\andre\vs cpp\Python Ordner\ChatBot\BluetoothGUI.py", line 234, in <lambda>
    button = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.new_window, text=(f"{addr} - {name} "), font=('Arial', 18, 'bold'), width=30, height=2, command = lambda a=addr, n = name, s = side : self.enter_headphone(a, n, s))
                                                                                                                                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\andre\vs cpp\Python Ordner\ChatBot\BluetoothGUI.py", line 242, in enter_headphone
    self.headphone_user = client(str(addr).lower(), None)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\andre\vs cpp\Python Ordner\ChatBot\BluetoothGUI.py", line 35, in __init__
    self.client.connect((mac_addr, self.PORT))
OSError: [WinError 10064] Bei einem Socketvorgang ist ein Fehler aufgetreten, da der
Zielhost nicht verfügbar war   (#added by me: english: [WinError 10064] A socket operation failed because the
Target host was not available)
```

Here is my client Code.

```
class client():
    count = 0
    def __init__(self, mac_addr, language1):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
        # self.client = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
        self.PORT = 4
        self.HEADER = 128
        self.FORMAT = 'utf-8'
        self.client.connect((mac_addr, self.PORT))
        self.language = language1
        
        self.DISCONNECT = '!DISCONNECT'
        self.thread_queue = Queue()
        
        
        
        thread = threading.Thread(target = self.handle_server)
        thread.start()
        # self.thread_transcribe = threading.Thread(target = self.transcribe, args = (self.language,  ))
        
    def send_msg(self,msg):
        encoded_msg = msg.encode(self.FORMAT)
        msg_length = len(encoded_msg)
        send_length = str(msg_length).encode(self.FORMAT)
        send_length += b' ' * (self.HEADER - len(send_length))
        self.client.send(send_length)
        self.client.send(encoded_msg)
        
        
    def handle_server(self):
        connected = True
        try:
            while connected:
                msg_length = self.client.recv(self.HEADER).decode(self.FORMAT)
                if msg_length:
                    try:
                        msg_length = int(msg_length)
                    except:
                        msg_length = len(msg_length)
                    msg = self.client.recv(msg_length).decode(self.FORMAT)
                    if msg.startswith('[0//])'):
                        audio_recv = self.client.recv(4096)
                        audio = pickle.loads(audio_recv)
                        thread = threading.Thread(target = self.play_audio, args = (audio,))
                        self.thread_queue.put(thread)
                        self.thread_start()
        except OSError as e:
            pass
        
        self.client.close()
```

Here is my GUI Code:

```
class Retra_GUI(ctk.CTk, client):
    
   
    def __init__(self):
        ctk.set_appearance_mode('Dark')
        ctk.set_default_color_theme('green')
        self.headphone_user = None
        self.headphone_user2 = None

        self.window = ctk.CTk()
        self.window.geometry('1000x800')
        self.window.title('ReTra')
        self.window.resizable(False,False)
        title_label = ctk.CTkLabel(master = self.window, text = 'ReTra', font  = ('Arial', 36, 'bold'))
        title_label.pack(padx = 10, pady  = 10 )

        self.headset_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master = self.window)
        self.headset_frame.pack(padx = 50, pady = 50, anchor = 'nw', fill = 'x')

        
        self.headset_one = ctk.CTkButton(master = self.headset_frame, text = 'Select Headphone', font = ('Arial', 32, 'bold'), command = lambda:  self.select_headphone('left') )
        self.headset_one.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10, side = 'left')
        self.headset_two = ctk.CTkButton(master = self.headset_frame, text = 'Select Headphone', font = ('Arial', 32, 'bold'), command = lambda: self.select_headphone('right') )
        self.headset_two.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10, side = 'right')


        self.window.mainloop()
    
    def select_headphone(self, side):
        nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names = True)
        self.new_window = ctk.CTkToplevel(self.window)
        self.new_window.title('Select Headphone')
        self.new_window.geometry('800x600')
        i = 0
        for addr, name in nearby_devices:
                                                                                    
            button = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.new_window, text=(f"{addr} - {name} "), font=('Arial', 18, 'bold'), width=30, height=2, command = lambda a=addr, n = name, s = side : self.enter_headphone(a, n, s))
            button.grid(row=i, column=0)      
            i += 1      

    def enter_headphone(self, addr, name, side1):
        if side1 == 'left':
            print(addr.lower(), name, side1)
            
            self.headphone_user = client(str(addr).lower(), None)
            self.headset_one = ctk.CTkButton(master = self.headset_frame, text = (f"{addr} - {name} "), font = ('Arial', 32, 'bold'), command = lambda s = side1 : self.select_headphone(s))
            self.headset_one.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10, side = 'left')
        
        else:
            self.headphone_user2 = client(str(addr).lower(), None)
            self.headset_two = ctk.CTkButton(master = self.headset_frame, text = (f"{addr} - {name} "), font = ('Arial', 32, 'bold'), command = lambda s = side1 : self.select_headphone(s))
            self.headset_two.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10, side = 'right')
        self.new_window.destroy()
```

In the following you will se my Server Code.

I used Port = 4 just because i saw it in a video of neurallink, i think.
But i dont think the mistake is in this code

Server Code (Server.py):

```
class server():
   

    def __init__(self, mac_adress):
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
        
        self.PORT = 4
        self.HEADER = 128
        self.FORMAT = 'utf-8'
        self.server.bind((mac_adress, self.PORT))
        self.translator = Translator()
        self.language1 = None
        self.language2 = None
        self.connections_list = []
        self.DISCONNECT = '!DISCONNECT'
        try:
            self.server.listen()
            print('Server listening...')
            while True:
                conn, addr = self.server.accept()
                thread = threading.Thread(target = self.handle_client, args = (conn, addr))
                thread.start()
                time.sleep(0.25)
        except OSError as e:
            pass
        
        self.server.close()
    # More irrelevant code...
```

I am very thankfull for every answer and please dont mind my english!

(moduls I imported:)

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import socket
import uuid
import time
import threading

import speech_recognition as sr
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from googletrans import Translator
from gtts import gTTS
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
import nltk
from langid import classify
import random

import pickle
import os

import bluetooth
from gtts.lang import tts_langs
from queue import Queue
```

Hello. I am trying to connect my bluetooth headphones (airpods) with my pc. I use the modul socket to establish a socket connection with the server(pc), the client(headphones), and the modul bluetooth to determine the mac adress of the airpods.  I also integrated a GUI with customtkinter.
I achieved creating a bluetooth socket connection between my second laptop(client) and my main laptop(server), but if i try connecting my airpods following error message comes up:

Or is their a possibility that the moduls pybluez oder socket are not able to pair?

Comment: The "port" is the channel number.  You have to know what channel to use.  Have you tried others?  And do you know whether you have to be a client or a server for the AirPods?

Comment: i tried 4, 5 and 1. But if i use port = 1, i get an error message that i dont have enough permission or something like that. 4 and 5 are the same. To the second question, my idea was to send speech input from one client(airpods) to another client2(headphone). I used speech recognition to listen to the mic and send it in a text to the server in order to translate it to another language and make a audio file and send it to client2. But I think that pybluez and socket dont support bluetooth pairing, because the connection with my other laptop worked

Comment: `pybluez` certainly does support pairing.  You can't use the device unless it has been paired.  `pybluez` is absolutely the right way to do what you're doing.  However, I suspect you don't really understand what you're in for here.  You would need to understand and implement the Bt audio protocols to do anything useful.  That's not trivial.  Don't your devices appear as Windows audio devices?  Can't you just use the Windows audio APIs, and leave the low-level stuff to existing drivers?

Comment: i actually started programming with python 2 months ago and I wanted to learn more about socket programming, so i am just a newbie. "You would need to understand and implement the Bt audio protocols to do anything useful. That's not trivial." i  tried looking which bt audio i should use. A2DP was the right one, i think, but pybluez doesnt support this protocol, so i just used RFCOMM.   "Don't your devices appear as Windows audio devices? Can't you just use the Windows audio APIs, and leave the low-level stuff to existing drivers? ": Yeah, i guess i could use it, but i wanted to try something n

Comment: Bt audio and video is an icky area.  My advice is to treat this as an audio problem, not as a Bt problem.

Comment: okay understand, thank you for your help. But lets say i would use an windows audio apis, do i still need a bluetooth socket? Can't I just connect two headphones to my PC via Bluetooth and then deal with the input and output of the microphones of the headphones and speakers?

Comment: You treat them just like a normal microphone and a normal speaker.  That's the beauty of the abstraction.  You don't need to CARE what the lowest-level protocol is. You focus on solving your problem.